# How to have \section{...} numbered as if it were a \subsection{...} but keep the same formatting

Tags: sectioning, numbering

So I'm a student writing chapter summaries for final exam preparation. I'm using the 'article' documentclass and am using separate documents for each chapter. How can I have `\section{...}` numbered as if it were a `\subsection{...}`, but keep the same font size/style. Just a note, I will be removing numbering from all instances of `\subsection{...}`and `\subsection{...}` too.

Here is a working example (per Werner's request). I want...

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1} 

\begin{document}
\section{The Nature of Chemical Energy and Redox Reactions}
\subsection{The Structure and Function of ATP}
\subsubsection{Term Defintions}
\end{document}
```

to print...

> 1.1 The Nature of Chemical Energy and Redox Reactions
>
> The Structure and Function of ATP
>
> Term Definitions

(edited for clarity)

Comment: Would you be able to publish a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that should your current single document and setup? We want to know, for example, what `1` in `1.2` represents? Also, why should `\section` be numbered, but not `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`? Have you made specific settings to have this so?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: The outcome of the numbering does depend on the class you're using. For example, for a `report` class, `\thesection` is already printed as `1.1` (= `\thechapter.\arabic{section}`). The counter `secnumdepth` helps with the un-numbering part of your question (i.e. `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}`).

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I noticed that although you have up-voted answers (which is great), you still haven't accepted any of them; accepting answers is a different action and can be done for those answers you consider best solved your problems by clicking the checkmark to their left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\summarynumber}{1} % adjust for the other summaries
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\summarynumber.\arabic{section}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1} % only sections are numbered
```

It's better to have an explicitly defined `\summarynumber` rather than burying the number in the redefinition of `\thesection`, for better ease of use.

You should be able to use any class you like, not anly `article`.

Comment: Thank you, egreg. That solved it. Thanks also to Werner, doncherry and Qrrbrbirlbel. I've edited the question for formatting and will keep your tips in mind for further posts.